# Update Auth Model from a deprecated version of Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following deprecated code:

```py
class samberos(User):
    objects = UserManager()
    backstage = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Si el sambero esta activo, pero no tocando instrumentos ... ")
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
    movil = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Este es el numero para los SMS")
    instrumento = models.ForeignKey(instrumentos)
    def url(self):
            return u'<a href="/samberos/' + self.username + u'/" title="' + self.username + u'" rel="gb_page_center[400, 210]">' + self.username + u'</a>'
    class Meta:
            ordering = ['username']
            verbose_name_plural = "samberos"
            verbose_name = "samberos"
```

And I want to update it to a newer version of django with is not supported at this moment and don't want to lost the users. How can I do it?

Now I running the version 1.8 and when I ran the server I got the following error:

```py
ERRORS:
actuaciones.samberos.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

The version of django used to create this code was 1.2 and was working fine with 1.4

Comment: Which version of Django are you upgrading to, and why does the above code not work?

Comment: So you seem to have set the AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to something else. If you want this code to continue to work, don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I highly recommend migrating those fields to a `UserProfile` model.

This is because django recommends using a `OneToOneField` with the `User` model, not inheriting it (this won't only solve this problem, but will set you on standard, avoiding future unknown problems).

As stated in the [documentation about additional fields for users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users):

> If you’d like to store additional information related to your users, Django provides a method to specify a site-specific related model – termed a “user profile” – for this purpose.

Of course, you will need a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to migrate your old information to this new model, but I can assure you, it will be worth it to stay in sync with the current standard.